# angular 4 Bind a promise in a class and get it resolved by its object

Tags: angular, promise

I'm trying to bind a promise inside a class and then wanted to resolved it after some things executed with that class object.
But i am getting null when i am accessing the promise property through its object.
Here is the code i'm trying,

```
    // li is object consiting  filterInfo array, filterInfo is the Object of
    // FilterInfo defined below
    for(var info of li.filterInfo) {
       console.log('test -1');
       myPromises.push(info.status);
     }
    console.log(myPromises);// this is returning undefined promises
    export class FilterInfo {

      public name:string;
      public type:string;
      public priority:number;
      public placeholder:string;
      public functionName: string;
      public flag?: boolean = false;
      private _loop?: boolean = true;
      public status?: Promise<boolean> = new Promise( (resolve, reject) => 
      {resolve(true)});



    }
```

Also i wanted to resolve that promise using the class object.
The problem is i am looping the components and those needs to be set before i do some other task.

Comment: where does `li` come from? Also please fix your formatting.

Comment: @j2l4e added the info reg li, is this possible ?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]